# Regex with nested repetition

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to create a regex in Go that matches up to 50 words separated by white space where each word is 1-32 "a"s
I'm using the following regex

```
regexp.Compile(`^(a{1,32}\s?){1,50}$`)
```

and I am getting the following error

```
error parsing regexp: invalid repeat count: `{1,50}`
```

I've noticed that it does work up to 31 repetitions like so

```
r, err := regexp.Compile(`^(a{1,32}\s?){1,31}$`)
```

see https://go.dev/play/p/RLnroX9-57_m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go's `regexp` engine has [a limit](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/581a822a9ed8fcae4afbc93daa6a74db7d9ea9a2/src/regexp/syntax/parse.go#L446) where combination of top level and any inner repetitions must not exceed 1000 copies of the innermost repeated part. This is documented in [re2 Syntax spec](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

In your case up to 31 works because inner 32 * outer 31 = 992. 32 * 32 = 1024 and also 32 * 50 = 1600 won't work for exceeding that limit.

Workaround is to split expression into multiple parts: `^(a{1,32}\s?){1,31}(a{1,32}\s?){0,19}$`